# PowerShell GUI - Data that don't get loaded right in the GUI

Tags: powershell, listview, user-interface

I am coding a xml gui reader just for fun but i am having some problem on how to populate the listview with the data.

When i run the PowerShell script: [img1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D93sS.png)

How the error looks like when i hit the search button:
[img2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w2MRa.png)

The data on the left screen is correct but it should be uploaded in the listview, when i hit search button.

The Query :

```
$GetXmlFileNames =  Get-ChildItem -Path $ApplicationFormTextboxUncPath -Recurse -force -Include $ApplicationFormButtonSearchFileTypes | Select-String -Pattern $Pattern | Format-List Filename, Path | Out-String

ForEach ($Object in $GetXmlFileNames){   

    Write-Host $GetXmlFileNames
        % { 
        if ($XML.Options.FileInfo.FileName.Enabled -eq $True) {
        Foreach-Object {
                        # Populate the XML columns with data
                        # Start Color
                        $SItem = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem(" Start - File Attribute ")
                        $SItem.BackColor = "Black"
                        $SItem.ForeColor = "White"
                        $LvMain.Items.Add($SItem)

                        # Xml File
                        $Item = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem(" Xml - FileName :")
                        $Item.SubItems.Add($_.Filename) }
                        $LvMain.Items.Add($Item)  

                        #Xml DirectoryName
                        $Item = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem(" Xml - DirectoryName :")
                        $Item.SubItems.Add($_.Path) }
                        $LvMain.Items.Add($Item) 

                        $EItem = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem(" End - File Attribute ")
                        $EItem.BackColor = "Red"
                        $EItem.ForeColor = "Black"
                        $LvMain.Items.Add($EItem)
                        }
```

The Project : https://github.com/fardinbarashi/Powershell-XmlPatternLookUp

Ps Code
 : https://github.com/fardinbarashi/Powershell-XmlPatternLookUp/blob/master/labxml.ps1

Now my idea is that the Filename and Path that you see in the IMG2 should be loaded in the listview ( LvMain )

How can i do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this you will need a GridView instead of a ListView, and add data bindings in your XAML for them.

Previous post on here details several approaches to it:

[Using XAML/WPF in PowerShell, how do I populate a list box?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29544866/using-xaml-wpf-in-powershell-how-do-i-populate-a-list-box)

Looks like that person was having the same issue you are, with trying to use the .Add() method on a function instead of having databindings.

Comment: na mate i solved it, by exporting the data to csv file and then populate it.
Its the Select-string that i think is messing it up

Comment: ok, good to know. figured Gridview would make more sense since it involved a graphic, cheers nonetheless